# extracting wikipedia article text with Cloud9 and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, wikipedia

First off: I'm on a new Mac Book, running El Capitan 10.11.3 and I just downloaded the latest Hadoop (2.6.0).

I am trying to use Cloud9 to extract the main article text from a bunch of pages in the wikipedia dump. Basically, they tell you how to do that as their second "quick and dirty" example on this documentation page:
http://lintool.github.io/Cloud9/docs/content/wikipedia.html

I downloaded everything and put in the same command in my terminal:

```
hadoop jar target/cloud9-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-fatjar.jar edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.DumpWikipediaToPlainText \ -input /wiki-sample.xml -wiki_language en -output wiki-sample-output.txt
```

SIDENOTE: I created a sample .xml with the first 1500 or so lines of the massive wiki dump and then the last couple pages from the end of the wiki dump. I'm just trying to get this to work before I try to run it for real.

Anyway, so I run that command and it seems to be doing something and then just prints out a bunch of quasi-documentation on the command line:

```
usage: edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.DumpWikipediaToPlainText
 -input <path>                              XML dump file
 -output <path>                             output path
 -wiki_language <en|sv|de|cs|es|zh|ar|tr>   two-letter language code
Generic options supported are
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
-jt <local|resourcemanager:port>    specify a ResourceManager
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated    archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.

The general command line syntax is
bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]
```

None of this seems particularly helpful and, most importantly, it does NOT create the output file with the article text. I've also tried creating a (blank) output file with the right name to see if it would fill it, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to using hadoop, so I'm hoping it's something simple that I'm missing. The Cloud9 page notes that "as of December 2015, this library is no longer being actively developed or maintained" so I really hope someone here can help me. Thanks a lot.
Seth

BRIEF ADDENDUM: 
I also tried going back to the root directory and running everything with full paths and bin/hadoop at the beginning, but that did the same thing. Here was my (unsuccessful) command from the root:

```
bin/hadoop jar /Users/Seth/Documents/Cloud9/target/cloud9-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-fatjar.jar edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.DumpWikipediaToPlainText \ -input /Users/Seth/Documents/Cloud9/wiki-sample.xml -wiki_language en -output /Users/Seth/Documents/Cloud9/wiki-sample-output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer to your particular question.

But if what you want to do is to get an easy, usable corpus out of  a wikipedia dump I recommend you using: https://github.com/idio/json-wikipedia

The parallel mode uses all the resources in your machine, and it won't take more than 30/45min for the english wikipedia in a macbook pro with roughly 16G of ram and 8cores

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may end up going with that, but I really just need the plain text of each article, not all of the links, references, etc. If I use this JSON parser (or something similar) then I'll have to go through and do another round of extraction on for each article. I was hoping to be able to do that all in one go (which was my attraction to Cloud9). Any ideas of something that can do that?

Comment: with a minor modification you could use: https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec which in its first step generates a corpus out of wikipedia text (One article's text per line). 

The only extra thing is that linked topics are added to the text as DBPEDIA/otherArticle

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I went ahead and used the json-wikipedia. It does take an extra step of then parsing the JSON, but it's still fairly easy to deal with.